# Force pyplot.imshow() to produce image with higher resolution

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, resolution

I have an NxN array that I am plotting in Python using `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()`.  N will be very large and I want my final image to have resolution to match.  However, in the code that follows, the image resolution doesn't seem to change with increasing N at all.  I think that `imshow()` (at least how I'm using it) has a fixed minimum pixel size that is larger than that needed to show my NxN array with full resolution.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

array = np.loadtxt("output.dat",unpack=True)
plt.figsize=(30.0, 30.0)
im = plt.imshow(array,cmap='hot')
plt.colorbar(im)
plt.savefig("mandelbrot.pdf")
```

As you can see in the code above, I've tried messing with `plt.figsize` to try and increase resolution but to no avail.  I've also tried various output formats (.pdf, .ps, .eps, .png) but these all produced images with lower resolution than I wanted.  The .ps, .eps, and .pdf images all looked the exact same.

First, does my problem exist with `imshow()` or is there some other aspect of my code that needs to be changed to produce higher resolution images?

Second, how do I produce higher resolution images?

Comment: Have you tried setting dpi in the `savefig()` call? `plt.savefig("mandelbrot.png", dpi=300)`

Comment: you can also set dpi in the figure http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure

Comment: I had not tried either of those.  I am using the `savefig()` one now.

Comment: @Ben The figure dpi and the save dpi are actually different for historical reasons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`plt.figsize()` will only change the size of the figure in inches while keeping the default dpi. You can set the resolution of the figure by passing the `dpi` keyword argument when you save the figure:

```
    fig.savefig('filename.extension', dpi=XXX)
```

So if you have a figure size of 4x6 and save it with `dpi=300` you'll end up with an image with 1200x1800 resolution.

You can also set the default figure size and dpi with [`matplotlibrc`](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html).