# Segmentation boundaries generated using Simple Linear Iterative Clustering in skimage are not well defined?

Tags: python, computer-vision, cluster-analysis, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I am using skimage slic clustering algorithm to segment a biomedical image (whole slide image). When I plot the image with the segment boundaries I find that the boundaries are not well defined. Below is the my code and the corresponding image. When I use a even higher resolution image I still have the same problem. Is this because the clustering algorithm can't find well defined segments? Is there a way of obtaining a well defined boundary?

```
from skimage.segmentation import slic
from skimage.segmentation import mark_boundaries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('testPatch2.png')
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

segments = slic(image, n_segments=500, sigma=5, enforce_connectivity=True, convert2lab=True)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(mark_boundaries(image, segments, mode='thick'))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Are you unhappy with your segmentation per se or just with the way it is displayed by matplotlib? Should the latter be the case, I would refer to @Juan. If it’s the segmentation result, I suggest you try alternatives to slic.

Comment: Just the maplotlib display, setting the dpi=300 worked thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an issue with the segmentation, but with the display. Matplotlib will by default crudely downsample the output image. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174359/plotting-at-full-resolution-with-matplotlib-pyplot-imshow-and-savefig), those linked therein, and the answers, for more details. You can fix this in different ways:

1. Set a higher DPI (dots per inch) by passing in `dpi=300` (for example) to the `plt.figure()` call.
2. Use `skimage.io.imsave` to save the image returned by `mark_boundaries`, then open it with a standard image viewer.